# Error: Request has been terminated superagent

Tags: reactjs, superagent

I am using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) 3.6.2, in a react project and keep getting:

```
Error: Request has been terminated
superagent/lib/client in crossDomainError
```

None of the users face any issue but my error logs are filled with these.

I make requests like this:

```
_pendingRequests[someKey] = req
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer XYZ`)
 .withCredentials()
 .end(handleRes(someKey, options));
}
```

and if the same request is hit twice I cancel the previous one:

```
 _pendingRequests[someKey]._callback = () => {};
 _pendingRequests[someKey].abort();
 _pendingRequests[someKey] = null;
```

Is there a reason why this is happening? Is it because of slow network on those devices or is it because of I am aborting a pending request?

Comment: when are you making the call ? What action leads to it ?

Comment: Any action that needs data from backend, a call is made to backend. But if the user refreshes the browser in between a network call that is in progress in background this error gets logged in sentry.

Comment: cool. I think thats a valid one and i believe you can safely ignore it on sentry. As one cannot do anything to prevent it. Sentry might have some filters to filter things out which you can make use of.